# How to launch Windows EXE from within Linux\UNIX host?

Tags: windows, linux, unix

I have a Windows Application that now I got a request to be triggered from within Linux machine. This app is expected to run independently on Windows itself, regardless of sharing info with Linux or something like that.

Well, I guess there are a couple of ways to apply it. e.g.: open SSH server (daemon) on Windows side that enables me to launch application from Linux client. However it enforces me to install such a daemon. I'm wondering if there is more simple solution that does not ask me to install any daemon/service on Windows side? Could I use WMI service somehow or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it not play well with Wine?

Comment: Actually he wants to trigger an application running on Windows using a Linux system. Aren't there tools that have externally accessible APIs for that? If not, some programming languages allow you to throw something together pretty easy, for example Google's own Go language.

Answer (score 0):

Found through google search, see if this helps:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx